# How to override product subtotal(line subtotal) price in woocomerce cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have custom products and i have added the products in the cart but it should be quantity based calculation for those products. how to change the product subtotal price in woocomerce. the product subtotal should override with my price. how to override it. Please check with my below code

```
 $values = array();
         $post_values = array();
         $i=0;
    foreach($_POST['post_quantity'] as $key =>$value){

            $values[] = "('{$_POST['product_id'][$key]}', '{$_POST['post_quantity'][$key]}', 
            '{$_POST['product_price'][$key]}', 
            '{$_POST['product_duplicate_price'][$key]}',
            '{$_POST['product_description'][$key]}',
            '{$_POST['product_material'][$key]}')";


$wpdb->insert('wp_posts', array(
      'post_title'    => 'xxxx '.$_POST['quoted_sid'].'Quote ID: '.$_POST['quoted_sid'][$key].'  - Product ID: '.$_POST['product_id'][$key],
      'post_content'  => $_POST['product_description'][$key],
      'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     =>'product'
    ));
    $lastid[$i] = $wpdb->insert_id; 

            $date[$i] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            //calculation for quantity 

                $regular_price =    
                $_POST['product_price'][$key] + $_POST['product_duplicate_price'][$key]*($_POST['post_quantity'][$key]-1);

             //$regular_price /$_POST['post_quantity'][$key];

            //echo number_format((float)$regular_price,2,'.','').'</br>';

        add_post_meta($lastid[$i], '_regular_price', number_format((float)$regular_price,2,'.',''));
        add_post_meta($lastid[$i], '_price', number_format((float)$_POST['product_price'][$key],2,'.',''));
        add_post_meta($lastid[$i],'_visibility','visible');

    add_post_meta($lastid[$i], '_stock_status', 'instock' );
    add_post_meta($lastid[$i], '_weight', '11' );
    add_post_meta($lastid[$i], '_sku', 'Quoted Stencil_'.$_POST['product_id'][$key] );
    add_post_meta($lastid[$i], '_duplicate_price', $_POST['product_duplicate_price'][$key] );
    add_post_meta($lastid[$i], '_material', $_POST['product_material'][$key] );

    $post_values['product_id'][] = $lastid[$i];
    $post_values['product_quantity'][] = $_POST['post_quantity'][$key];
    $i++;
    }

    //print_r($post_values);




        $j=0;



        foreach ( $post_values as $product_id ) {


$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $post_values['product_id'][$j] ,$post_values['product_quantity'][$j],$cart_item_data);
            $j++;
        }
    //exit;

     exit( wp_redirect( home_url( "cart" ) ) );
```

Comment: Why exit( wp_redirect( home_url( "cart" ) ) ); ? Yo need to use wp_redirect( home_url( "/cart" ); exit();  instead.

Comment: How to override the row subtotal.

Comment: What do you want to override? Change subtotal price or what?

Comment: each individulal product total

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter called "woocommerce_cart_subtotal" for this. It is a filter for final string ( currency+subtotal+vat text). If you have some custom calculation for subtotal, inject it to this filter.

First test it and make sure it works.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_subtotal','subtotalchanger',0);
function subtotalchanger($subtotal){
    return $subtotal.' - it worked';
}
```

If everything is ok, then place your custom calculation to this filter and return your own subtotal:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_subtotal','subtotalchanger',0);
function subtotalchanger($subtotal){
    //your own calculations based on cart products and their quantities
return $your_custom_subtotal
}
```

Comment: Changing product row subtotal not cart subtotal

Comment: can you add some screenshot about what you mean to change?

Comment: add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'on_display_cart_item_price_html', 100, 3);

Comment: This is the function i need to change each and individual product price on cart row